# cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: cross-compiling

I have a cross-compiler in my home folder on Ubuntu 13.10 (64-bit). I downloaded it [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) at the bottom of the page where it says "Prebuilt Toolchains". When I try to compile something it gives me this:

```
cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After goggling a little I found [this](http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/4190/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libmpc-so-2-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-d). I tried the commands the author wrote to enter; but they will not help me, since I am having this problem with a cross-compiler from the home dictionary, not the system compiler. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:** Here is the file I am trying to cross-compile:

```
void print(char *message, int line,int ch){
     char *vm=(char *)0xb8000;
     int i=(line*80*2);
     i=i+(ch*2);
     while(*message!=0){
     if (*message=='\n'){line++;
     i=(line*80*2);}
     else {vm[i]=*message;
     i++;
     vm[i]=0x07;
     i++;} *message++;}}

void kernel_main(){
print("Hello!\nHow do you like my kernel?",0,0);}
```

I also have an assembly file written in AT&T syntax that calls kernel_main().

Comment: Can you please provide more detail?  Which cross compiler, what command you are using, what system you are on, etc.

Comment: I just downloaded another cross-compiler from the same place an it does the same thing. Should I try Fedora instead of Ubuntu? Or is that just weired?

Comment: I just tried it on Fedora and it did not work either. Can anyone try the i386-elf cross-compiler from os-dev.org on their hardware? Maybe it's just my computer that has this problem for some reason.

Comment: I downloaded two more cross-compilers from OS-dev.org and they have the same problem. I am obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: CAn u tell me what are you trying to cross compile?

Answer (score 14):

My error disappeared after I had issued the following commands:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
sudo ldconfig
```

`ldconfig` is the magic.

Comment: libstdc++.so.6.0.20-gdb.py is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at start.

Answer (score 5):

Could you find libmpc.so.3 in /usr/lib or /usr/lib64? If you found it or the same thing, you need replace it with libmpc.so.2 file. That file can find in different Linux version lower.

Comment: In my case I just linked libmpc.so.2 to libmpc.so.3 and recompiled and that seems to work also. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I solved `cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2` as follows:

Install `libmpc3` via repo and make symlink (dirty method, but worked):

```
sudo apt-get install libmpc*
```

or (if toolchain for i386):

```
sudo apt-get install libmpc*:i386
```

in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` for i386 or in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` for amd64:

```
sudo ln -s libmpc.so.3.0.0 libmpc.so.2
```

Answer (score 2):

version 2 of libmpc (i.e. libmpc.2.dynlib) is build from versions 0.7 - 0.9 of the source (find the download archives at [www.multiprecision.org](http://www.multiprecision.org/index.php?prog=mpc&page=download)). Versions earlier than 0.9 appear to be incompatible with newer versions of [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) so I'd try building that one first. I was able to build and use 0.9 on my OsX El Capitan system after installing gcc 4.8, gmp, and mpfr:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install gcc48
brew install gmp
brew install mpfr
```

Then in the mpc-0.9 dirctory:

```
./configure  --with-gmp=/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.0 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/Cellar/mpfr/3.1.3
make
sudo make install
```